# dropboxd hangs at `Connecting...` when started trough systemd on boot

Tags: systemd, dropbox, netcfg

I've got a systemd service file `dropbox.service` set up as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=dropbox
After=local-fs.target network.target

[Service]
User=romeovs
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dropboxd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

this succesfully starts the dropbox daemon if it is run any time after boot. Something seems to go wrong when I `enable` it to run at boot though. `dropbox status` just shows that dropbox is `Connecting...`.

My guess is that the network needs to be fully up before dropbox is started. How can I force this with systemd?

Comment: There are a couple of [hacks on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dropbox#Connecting...) to address this issue...

Answer (score 1):

As a quick hack:

```
[Unit]
Description=dropbox
After=local-fs.target network.target

[Service]
User=romeovs
ExecStartPre=sh -c 'while ! ping -c1 dropbox.com >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dropboxd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Should work independently of what any network manager reports.